# golang, £ char causing weird Â character

Tags: go

I have a function that generates a random string from a string of valid characters. I'm occasionally getting weird results when it selects a £

I've reproduced it to the following minimal example:

```
func foo() string {
    validChars := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~@:!£$%^&*"
    var result strings.Builder

    for i := 0; i < len(validChars); i++ {

        currChar := validChars[i]
        result.WriteString(string(currChar))
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

I would expect this to return

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~@:!£$%^&*`

But it doesn't, it produces

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~@:!Â£$%^&*
                                                                  ^
                                             where did you come from ?
```

if I take the £ sign out of the original validChars string, that weird A goes away.

```
func foo() string {
    validChars := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~@:!$%^&*"
    var result strings.Builder

    for i := 0; i < len(validChars); i++ {

        currChar := validChars[i]
        result.WriteString(string(currChar))
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

This produces
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789~@:!$%^&*`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `string` is a type alias for `[]byte`. Your mental model of a `string` is probably that it consists of a slice of characters - or, as we call it in Go: a slice of `rune`.

For many runes in your `validChars` string this is fine, as they are part of the ASCII chars and can therefore be represented in a single byte in UTF-8. However, the `£` rune is represented as 2 bytes.

Now if we consider a string `£`, it consists of 1 rune but 2 bytes. As I've mentioned, a string is really just a `[]byte`. If we grab the first element like you are effectively doing in your sample, we will only get the first of the two bytes that represent `£`. When you convert it back to a string, it gives you an unexpected rune.

---

The fix for your problem is to first convert string `validChars` to a `[]rune`. Then, you can access its individual runes (rather than bytes) by index, and `foo` will work as expected. You can see it in action in [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QDuHPh34UOI).

Also note that `len(validChars)` will give you the count of bytes in the string. To get the count of runes, use [`utf8.RuneCountInString`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#RuneCountInString) instead.

Finally, [here](https://blog.golang.org/strings)'s a blog post from Rob Pike on the subject that you may find interesting.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! This helped a lot.

Comment: Happy to help! Also I have just edited my answer with a reference to a blog post, in case you're interested in more context about this